# How can I calculate a point between two given points in processing?

Tags: java, math, coordinates, line, processing

I have two given coordinates, for example (20,30) and (90,40). How can I find out a point on the line between these two points?

I need to do this in processing but also a general mathematical solution would help me.

Comment: I have tried nothing. I thought there must be a simple formel but I found nothing on the web so far.

Comment: Search for the term "interpolation."

Comment: the mathematical basics are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Comment: Interpolation was the word! I found the lerp() function for processing and that makes exactly what I need. I kiss you!

Answer (score 5):

To find the midpoint, just use the midpoint formula:

```
float midX = (pOne.x + pTwo.x)/2;
float midY = (pOne.y + pTwo.y)/2;
```

To find another point on the line, you could use Processing's built-in `lerp()` function.

```
float midX = lerp(pOne.x, pTwo.x, .5);
float midY = lerp(pOne.y, pTwo.y, .5);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html).

Comment: The lerp() function makes exactly what I need. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can interpolate with

```
x = (0, 1); // anything between 0 and 1
c = x * a + (1 - x) * b;
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are points.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesnt have lerp so here it is how it works in general

```
float lerp(float point1, float point2, float dist) {
    return point1 + dist * (point2 - point1);
}
```